# Limit html page scrolling / Get rid of excess below non-repeating background image

Tags: html, css, image, background, scroll

Let's say there is a page I want but I do not want anyone to scroll past 1280 px (length) & 800 px (width). I have a non-repeating background image via CSS on this page, but some excess nothingness appears below & to the right of it. OR is there a way to get rid of such excess?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.
"Look at the comments for more details" - no please don't do that. 1) formatting of code in comments is atrocious - it's impossible t read. 2) people won't read comments, and it's unfair for you to force them to do so. Please instead edit your question and put all the relevant information into there. Your question should be a complete explanation of the problem - that lets us help you better by being easily able to find all relevant info.

Comment: It also helps anybody else with a similar problem easily spot whether your problem is the same as theirs (and whether any solutions here will help them).  Which is important to us here at Stack Overflow. So please edit your question and make it better for everyone. thanks :)

Comment: If you saw the other comment on code, I am struggling to put in the code in comments correctly. I don't know how forgiving you are, but that's something that I tried to do here & failed so please bare with me.

Comment: yes, it is not possible to format code in comments. so don't put it in comments please :)
Instead edit your original question, and put the code in there instead.

Comment: For us to help you - we need to see you original code (and can then tell you what to change to make it work). Surely you have some html code... otherwise how are you putting the image on the page? Your question mentions CSS - so we would all naturally assume that you know where CSS goes to make it work... if not - please edit your question and explain what skills you do and do not have, and what you tried, and what results you got when you googled for "how to use css" :)

Answer (score 0):

try set your background image or body to `width:"1280px" height:"800px"`

Comment: How would you put that in?

Comment: width:"1280px";
height:"800px";

Comment: Pardon this, 3450475, I'm still trying to figure out how to put in code

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS:

```
background-image:url(xyz.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
```

Comment: It got rid of the excess, but it scrolls the text while my background image is still.

Comment: background-size:100% 100%

Comment: It still does the same thing

Comment: what else do u need...stop text scrolling also ??

Comment: Is it possible? Or am I asking for too much?

Comment: I m not sure that will work or not..wait for some more answers

Comment: This is something that I was hoping to get done today, but I am trying to do all this upon request, so I'm sorry for anyone who doesn't follow why I need to know how to do this.